# Get the position in a ListView for an row with a certain id

Tags: android, android-listview, click, simplecursoradapter

I have a `ListView` with a `SimpleCursorAdapter` and I wonder how to get a position in `ListView` for an id? I need it to perform a click on particular row of the list like this

```
lv.performItemClick(lv, pos, lv.getItemIdAtPosition(pos));
```

Comment: Question is a little unclear. Do you want to get the position number of an item in your ListView given the _id from your local database? Or the other way around?

Comment: if your itemClickListener doesn't use the id, you can safely ignore it (pass -1 or something)

Comment: I whant to use _id from table (it is called "_id")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Iterate over your `Cursor` used in the `SimpleCursorAdapter` and check the ids:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast) {
         if (cursor.getLong(/*the index of the _id column*/) == theTargetId) {
              theWantedPosition = cursor.getPosition();
              break; 
         }
         cursor.moveToNext();
    } 
}
lv.performItemClick(lv, theWantedPosition, lv.getItemIdAtPosition(theWantedPosition));
```

Comment: shorter version is to iterate on pos in 0..adapter.getCount() with comparing adapter.getItemId(pos) (although probably less efficient)

Comment: @njzk2 You could use `getItemId()` and test for each position until you have a match, but is basically the same code as `getItemId` moves the `Cursor` to the position provided as the parameter. But my code does this without the overhead(although insignificant most likely) of needing to call an extra wrapper method.

Comment: yes (which is why i think it wouldn't be as efficient as your solution (I think getItemId uses cursor.moveToPosition, which may not be as good as move to next). It would simply use less lines and look more straightforward (and be compatible with other listadapters)

Answer (score 0):

This override method will give you position of this clicked listView

```
 @Override
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    }
```

Comment: I cannot click on this position, this is new, just inserted line.